# Hibernate One to One mapping issue - Cascade feature not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have following HBM entity classes:

1. Train.java, Ticket.java, Booking.java, Passenger.java

I have `One-to-One` relationship between Booking and Ticket.
Please find below hibernate pojo classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TICKET_MASTER")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Ticket implements Serializable {

@Transient
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "TICKET_SEQ")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "TICKET_SEQ", sequenceName = "TICKET_SEQ",  allocationSize = 1)
@Column(name = "TICKET_ID", nullable = false)
private Long ticketId;

@Column(name = "TICKET_NO", nullable = false)
private String ticketNo;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "ticket",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Booking booking;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "ticket")
private Set<Passenger> passengers;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "TRAIN_ID", nullable = false)
private Train train;

//getters & setters
 }

@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOKING_MASTER")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Booking extends RMSEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "BOOKING_SEQ")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "BOOKING_SEQ", sequenceName = "BOOKING_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
  @Column(name = "BOOKING_ID", nullable = false)
  private Long bookingId;

  @Column(name = "BOOKING_NO", nullable = false)
  private String bookingNo;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "TICKET_ID", referencedColumnName = "TICKET_ID")
  private Ticket ticket;

  //gettres & setters
 }
```

I am ommitting the pojo classes for Passenger and Train since problem occurred between above two classes.

Please find below my service layer code:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = { Throwable.class })
@Override
public void saveBookingDetails(PassengerDTO passengerDTO) {
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(passengerDTO, passenger);*/
    Train train = getDaoProvider().getTrainDao().find(passengerDTO.getTrainId());
    Ticket ticket = new Ticket();
    ticket.setTicketId((long) (Math.random() * 100));
    String ticketNo = UUID.randomUUID().toString().split("-")[0];
    ticket.setTicketNo(ticketNo);
    Booking booking = new Booking();
    String bookingNo = UUID.randomUUID().toString().split("-")[0];
    booking.setBookingId((long)(Math.random() * 100)); 
    booking.setBookingNo(bookingNo); 
    ticket.setBooking(booking); 
    ticket.setTrain(train); 
    getDaoProvider().getTicketDao().saveOrUpdate(ticket);
   }
```

I am getting following exception:

```
Caused By: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:112)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:119)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatch.java:97)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SYSTEM"."TICKET_MASTER"."BOOKING_ID")

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:12296)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:246)
at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:197)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:110)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatch.java:97)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

I am using Spring-Hibernate ORM feature.

Answer (score 1):

In bidirectional relation you should have a reference from each side to the other, you missed injecting the ticket in the booking , same for train.

```
Booking booking = new Booking();
booking.setTicket(ticket);
train.setTicket(ticket);
String bookingNo = UUID.randomUUID().toString().split("-")[0];
```

Another thing , since your id in the booking is autogenerated you should not set the id, hibernate will take care of assigning id to it on persistance

```
String bookingNo = UUID.randomUUID().toString().split("-")[0];// this line should be removed
booking.setBookingId((long)(Math.random() * 100));//this line should be removed
ticket.setTicketId((long) (Math.random() * 100));//this line should be removed
```

Also remove the line setting id for Ticket as well.

Also since you are using sequence generation you need to specify the type to be sequence not auto

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "BOOKING_SEQ")
```

Comment: @SumitGhosh check now

Comment: No.I think there is some issue with cascading.
I have made all the changes suggested by you but still getting same error

Comment: @SumitGhosh I think the error is related to the constraint of the train, establishing relation with train has the same issue as booking, i edited my answer , but you need to consider all the points i mentioned

Answer (score 0):

`mappedBy` means that this side of relation haven't access to cascade (manipulate data) relation object because it's not the owner entity.
if you want to cascade that entity you should be owner of it, so you can remove `mappedBy` parameter and add `@JoinColumn` under `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.All`.

Comment: This is definitely not true. As Amer Qarabsa answered, you need to set both sides before persisting. Or you can also remove the not null constraint on BOOKING_ID. In that case hibernate will add it first as NULL, and update it afterwards